# Google Maps Geocoding API

Tags: javascript, google-maps

The following code displaying map and also displaying the div portion but not displaying the marker point on the map can any one help me out thanks in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false">                                                            </script>

<script>
    var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(17.382094947877505,78.431396484375);
    var geocoder,map;

    function initialize()
    {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var mapProp = {
            center:myCenter,
            zoom:5,
            mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
    }

    function codeAddress() {
        var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location
                });
            } else {
                alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
            }
        });
     }
     google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="pannel">
        <input type="address" type="textbox" value="hyderbad,Andhra Pradesh">
        <input type="button" value="Geocode" onclick="codeAddress();">
    </div>
    <div id="googleMap" style="width:1200px;height:800px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Declare your variables once, with var at the top (var map). 
Then simply re-assign them, without the var (in the initialize function)
http://jsfiddle.net/B5ZM7/

Comment: Next time, please put some time into formatting your code before posting it, it's really hard to muster strength to read your code if it isn't indented properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's 2 things you need to do to make your code work:

1. Make sure your input field has an `id` attribute (since you're using `document.getElementById`)
2. Don't reinitialize the `map` variable

So the address input should look like this:

```
<input id="address" type="text" value="hyderbad,Andhra Pradesh">
```

And the map instantiation:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
```

Here's the complete code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
   <script>
      var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(17.382094947877505,78.431396484375);
      var geocoder,map;

      function initialize() {
         geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
         var mapProp = {
            center:myCenter,
            zoom:5,
            mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
         };

         map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
      }

      function codeAddress() {
         var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
         geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
               map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
               var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  map: map,
                  position: results[0].geometry.location
               });
            } else {
               alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
            }
         });
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
   </script>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="panel">
      <input id="address" type="text" value="hyderbad,Andhra Pradesh">
      <input type="button" value="Geocode" onclick="codeAddress();">
   </div>
   <div id="googleMap" style="width:1200px;height:800px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```